# HTML file open dialog to access server file system

Tags: java, javascript, html, file-upload

Is is possible to have file open dialog box for displaying files and directories which is in server file system? I have a requirement in my web application where the user should select a file which is available in server.

Do we have any plugin for this or can it be possible using < input type="file" > component. Is it possible to achieve this, since when I googled I dint get any information. Please help me out. Any suggestions will be really appreciated.

Comment: No, you will have to build this yourself or use a ready-made component. The browser's file dialog will not help here in any case.

Answer (score 2):

Your application can request a list of files from a server. And a dialog box you can make youself.

Comment: But the file, user going to upload can be anywhere in server. If so then I have to traverse all the files ?

Comment: Server should send only a list of files in that directory where an user is. When the user changes directory your application sends request for a list of files in that directory. The application gets response and update the dialog box. And of course when I said "a list of files" I mean "a list of files' names"

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with ASP.Net... all you need is file system permissions and a simple file browser in a web page, and you can also rename files using the System.IO namespace. Through ASP.Net you can read and modify files on the server. But using JavaScript you will have limited access.

Comment: my application is a Java,J2EE based webapplication :(